# Defining the Default graphql in the GraphiQL Interface

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, graphiql

I'm new to Gatsby, and I'm having trouble understanding how the graphiQL interface is populated with a default query.

I'm comparing two Gatsby starters. One is called [photo book](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/baobabKoodaa/gatsby-starter-photo-book/) and the other is called [gatsby-creative](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/JohnJKerr/gatsby-creative/). I've downloaded and successfully executed both in develop mode. Both starters do in fact have graphQL queries used in the respective projects.  However, when I visit the graphiQL interface for both starters I notice the first starter has no default graphql content (left-most column) whereas the second starter does have a default query called `MyQuery`.

What part of a Gatsby project controls whether there is a default query shown in the graphiQL interface?  I can't figure it out and I've seen no documentation to explain this behavior.

Also, that second starter does have several graphQL queries, but none of them are named `MyQuery` (search for "myquery" turns up nothing). So it is particularly mysterious to me how the graphiQL interface obtains (or not) its default query.

Again, in what part of a Gatsby project should I look to discover which graphql statement is or is not part of pre-populating the graphiQL interface?

Comment: It might be the versions difference and nothing more